# Kafka broker restart with "Replication factor: 3 greater than broker 0."

Tags: apache-kafka

We have eight kafka brokers cluster with 5 zookeeper cluster in confluent-platform 7.0.1. For example when we restart broker id 2, according kafka log as fallowing

```
[2023-06-15 09:56:09,906] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /10.136.132.61:36972, server: datagovstg-kfk04.deltaww.com/10.136.132.62:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2023-06-15 09:56:10,013] INFO Session establishment complete on server datagovstg-kfk04.deltaww.com/10.136.132.62:2181, session id = 0x535f9587f0000, negotiated timeout = 18000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2023-06-15 09:56:10,014] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-06-15 09:56:11,283] INFO [feature-zk-node-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureChangeListener$ChangeNotificationProcessorThread)
[2023-06-15 09:56:11,483] INFO Updated cache from existing <empty> to latest FinalizedFeaturesAndEpoch(features=Features{}, epoch=0). (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureCache)
[2023-06-15 09:56:11,490] INFO Cluster ID = Xugt0nfcSjW7zXrDhEzkuA (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

// DELETED

[2023-06-15 09:56:13,644] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/2 (is it secure? false) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2023-06-15 09:56:13,732] INFO Stat of the created znode at /brokers/ids/2 is: 85899346228,85899346228,1686794161605,1686794161605,1,0,0,1466719931400192,329,0,85899346228
 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2023-06-15 09:56:13,732] INFO Registered broker 2 at path /brokers/ids/2 with addresses: PLAINTEXT://datagovstg-kfk03.deltaww.com:9092,SASL_PLAINTEXT://datagovstg-kfk03.deltaww.com:9093, czxid (broker epoch): 85899346228 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2023-06-15 09:56:13,789] INFO [ExpirationReaper-2-topic]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2023-06-15 09:56:13,793] INFO [ExpirationReaper-2-Heartbeat]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2023-06-15 09:56:13,794] INFO [ExpirationReaper-2-Rebalance]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2023-06-15 09:56:13,809] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2023-06-15 09:56:13,818] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2023-06-15 09:56:13,834] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=2] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2023-06-15 09:56:13,838] INFO [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 2]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
[2023-06-15 09:56:13,838] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=2] Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)

// DELETED

[2023-06-15 09:56:21,639] INFO Kafka version: 7.0.1-ccs (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-06-15 09:56:21,639] INFO Kafka commitId: b7e52413e7cb3e8b (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-06-15 09:56:21,639] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1686794181632 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-06-15 09:56:21,641] INFO [KafkaServer id=2] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-06-15 09:56:21,940] INFO [Admin Manager on Broker 2]: Error processing create topic request CreatableTopic(name='_schemas', numPartitions=3, replicationFactor=3, assignments=[], configs=[]) (kafka.server.ZkAdminManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 0.
[2023-06-15 09:56:21,994] INFO [Admin Manager on Broker 2]: Error processing create topic request CreatableTopic(name='__consumer_offsets', numPartitions=50, replicationFactor=3, assignments=[], configs=[CreateableTopicConfig(name='compression.type', value='producer'), CreateableTopicConfig(name='cleanup.policy', value='compact'), CreateableTopicConfig(name='segment.bytes', value='104857600')]) (kafka.server.ZkAdminManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 0.
[2023-06-15 09:56:22,095] INFO [Admin Manager on Broker 2]: Error processing create topic request CreatableTopic(name='_schemas', numPartitions=3, replicationFactor=3, assignments=[], configs=[]) (kafka.server.ZkAdminManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 0.
[2023-06-15 09:56:22,136] INFO [Admin Manager on Broker 2]: Error processing create topic request CreatableTopic(name='_schemas', numPartitions=3, replicationFactor=3, assignments=[], configs=[]) (kafka.server.ZkAdminManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 0.
[2023-06-15 09:56:22,174] INFO [Admin Manager on Broker 2]: Error processing create topic request CreatableTopic(name='__consumer_offsets', numPartitions=50, replicationFactor=3, assignments=[], configs=[CreateableTopicConfig(name='compression.type', value='producer'), CreateableTopicConfig(name='cleanup.policy', value='compact'), CreateableTopicConfig(name='segment.bytes', value='104857600')]) (kafka.server.ZkAdminManager)
```

Looks like broker id 2 has join cluster, but

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 0.
```

I write simple java program using bootstrap.server=broker1 to describe cluster, I can get broker 2 in available nodes. But I can not using bootstrap.server=broker2 to describe cluster or list topics. I use zookeeper-shell connect to zookeeper, I use this command `ls /brokers/ids` then I get eight broker id in children.
When I shutdown all kafka brokers and restart kafka brokers, this situation was disappear. I don't this this is right solution to handle this error.

We have some topics with only one replica. A colleague believes that this is the root cause and suggests that we should set the replication factor to 3 for each topic. The existing topics should be reassigned to have a replication factor of 3. Is this the root cause of the problem we are encountering?

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can try to find the root cause?

Comment: How did you create your cluster? Manually? Or using [Ansible](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-ansible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is related to your Schema Registry's bootstrap.server config, not Kafka itself, as that requires the `_schemas` and `__consumer_offsets` topic to exist, and the default replication factor for both is `3`.

If you aren't needing the Schema Registry, you can ignore that, but consumer clients will also not be able to read data with consumer groups without the `__consumer_offsets` topic, regardless of the number of brokers in the cluster, or what you've set as `bootstrap.servers` in them.